# 0x Kovan API returning 503 responses?

Tags: kovan, 0x

We have been using the Kovan 0x endpoint (https://kovan.api.0x.org/swap/v1) for a few months without trouble, but just started  receiving HTTP 503 responses back today. Is the endpoint still supported / who can we contact about the status of the endpoint?

```
<html>\r\n<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are in the process of deprecating the Kovan endpoint. We fully support the [0x Ropsten endpoint](https://ropsten.api.0x.org/) and we encourage all integrators to switch over to Ropsten as soon as possible.